# Sparql query containment result

Tags: sparql, owl, semantic-web

Not familiar with semantic web, under the following context:

```
// owl in terms of Java-like syntax
Class Person {}
Class GraduateStudent extends Person {reference takesCourse [*] : GraduateCourse}
Class Student intersect Person {reference takesCourse [*] : Course}
Class UndergradStudent extends Student {}

Class Course{}
Class GraduateCourse extends Course{}
Class CsCourse extends Course{}
```

My question is why Q1 ⊑ Q2 does not hold? In particular, if I understand correctly, `Q1` select undergraduate students take CsCourse and graduate students take GraduateCourse, and `Q2` select undergraduate students take any Course and graduate students take any Course:

```
// Q1:
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE 
{ 
  { ?x a :UndergradStudent .
    ?x :takesCourse ?y . 
    ?y a :CsCourse 
  }
    UNION 
  { ?x a :GraduateStudent .
    ?x :takesCourse ?y 
  }
}

// Q2: 
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE 
{ 
  {
    { 
      ?x a :UndergradStudent . 
      ?x :takesCourse ?y 
    }
     UNION 
    { 
      ?x a :GraduateStudent .
      ?x :takesCourse ?y 
    } 
   }
   ?y a :Course .
}
```

edit: this example can be found at: http://sparql-qc-bench.inrialpes.fr/UCQrdfs.html, Q43b and Q43c in particular.

Comment: The comparison is whether `Q1 ⊑ Q2`, i.e. is everything of `Q1` in `Q2` - this is clearly not the case given the outer `?y a :Course .` in `Q2`

Comment: Why do you think that undergraduade students take undergraduate cources only?

Comment: sorry @Stanislav Kralin, I don't understand your hint, do you agree with me that from the OWL definition all we know is that there are some `UndergradStudents` that take `Courses`, Q1 restricts this set to select `UndergradStudents` that take `CsCourses`, Q2 says select all `UndergradStudents` that take `Courses`, for this particular part of query containment checking, I think it is rather clear that Q1 ⊑ Q2. I miss something might be?

Comment: @AKSW thank you for your reply, there seems some misunderstanding of the semantics of SparQL on my part, do you mind to have a look at this question I just asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733756/sparql-query-equivlence

Comment: After reading [this](http://sparql-qc-bench.inrialpes.fr/about.html), I'm not sure that students takes cources only, i. e. the range of `:takesCourse` is `:Course`. Perhaps there are many additional ontological presuppositions in your questions.

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin, oh! I see, that is possible. To be honest, I cannot find the exact "prefix" used by this benchmark. The closest I can find is this one: http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl That is where I derive the ontology shown in this question. I ll dig again and conclude whether there is this possibility you suggest. Thank you!