# SPARQL query equivalence

Tags: sparql

Under the following context:

```
// owl in terms of Java-like syntax
Class Person {}
Class GraduateStudent extends Person {reference takesCourse [*] : GraduateCourse}
Class Student intersect Person {reference takesCourse [*] : Course}
Class UndergradStudent extends Student {}

Class Course{}
Class GraduateCourse extends Course{}
Class CsCourse extends Course{}
```

may I ask how should I read the following query?

```
// Q1: 
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE 
{ 
  {
    { ?x a :UndergradStudent . 
      ?x :takesCourse ?y }
     UNION 
    { ?x a :GraduateStudent .
      ?x :takesCourse ?y } 
  } 
   ?y a :Course .
}
```

I think it means select undergraduate students take any Course and graduate students take any Course, what bothers me to confirm this is the following:

- Is there suppose to be a dot before `?y a :Course`, such that the UNION-patterns inside `{...}` can be viewed as a single pattern to match, or it does not matter?
- Can I distribute `?y a :Course` over `UNION`, i.e. turn `Q1` into `Q2`.

:

```
// Q2: 
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE 
{ 
  {
    { ?x a :UndergradStudent . 
      ?x :takesCourse ?y .
      ?y a :Course }
     UNION 
    { ?x a :GraduateStudent .
      ?x :takesCourse ?y .
      ?y a :Course } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Last time you didn't reply to my comment...

Comment: 1) no need for a dot. 2) the result would be the same

Comment: @AKSW thank you, I feel closer to understand my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673086/sparql-query-containment-result